# Why would a cross-entropy approaching negative infinity?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm learning *Deep Learning* by Ian Goodfellow. In 6.2.1.1 it says

> For real-valued output variables, if the model can control the density of the output distribution (for example, by learning the variance parameter of a Gaussian output distribution) then it becomes possible to assign extremely high density to the correct training set outputs, **resulting in
> cross-entropy approaching negative infinity**.

But the cross-entropy is defined as

$$-\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_{data}}\log P_{model}(y|x)$$

or in the empirical form

$$-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m\log P_{model}(y|x)$$

As we can see it is bounded below by $-\log 1 = 0$. Then why the book says that it would approach negative infinity?

Any thought would help.

Comment: Try asking the question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Thanks! The question is explained in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/524305/321700